Understanding the reverse SDE
When reading papers/blogs about diffusion models, it is stated that if $X_t$ is the unique solution to an SDE $$dX_t=f dt+g dB_t,$$ where $B_t$ is the standard Brownian motion (starting from $B_0=0$), then its time-reverse $Y_t=X_{T-t}$, is the solution to
$$dY_t=f' dt+g' dB'_t,$$ for some functions $f', g'$ and a BM $B'_t$.
My questions are as follows.

What exactly this $B'_t$ should be? Is it some function of $B_t$, like $B'_t=-B_{T-t}$? Or is it just a standard BM? Under which case will the solution to $dY_t=f' dt+g' dB'_t$ with $Y_0=X_T$ is exactly $X_{T-t}$?
If we consider the discrete update for a fixed $\omega$: $$X_{t+\delta}(\omega)=X_t(\omega)+f(\omega) \delta+g(\omega) (B_{t+\delta}(\omega)-B_t(\omega)),$$ with $\delta\to 0$ and get a forward path; Then we start from $Y_0(\omega)=X_T(\omega)$ and update following the reverse SDE $$Y_{t+\delta}(\omega)=Y_t(\omega)+f'(\omega) \delta+g'(\omega) (B'_{t+\delta}(\omega)-B'_t(\omega)).$$ If $B'_t$ is some function of $B_t$ (some function $F$), then we can use the forward values ($B_t(\omega)$) to calculate the values of $B'_t(\omega)$ and use them to update the reverse sequence  $$Y_{t+\delta}(\omega)=Y_t(\omega)+f'(\omega) \delta+g'(\omega) (F(B_{t+\delta}(\omega))-F(B_t(\omega))).$$   Will the two sequences $X_i(\omega),Y_i(\omega)$ be identical (assuming $\delta$ is infinitesimal)?

EDIT: I tried on the simple SDE $dX_t=dB_t$, clearly $X_t=B_t\sim N(0,t)$. Accordingly, the reverse SDE is $dY_t=-\frac{Y_t}{T-t} dt +dB'_t$. By Ito formula we have $\frac{Y_t}{T-t}=\frac{Y_0}{T}+\int^t_0 \frac{dB's}{T-s}$. Now if $B'_t$ is just a standard BM, then $Y_t\sim N(0,T-t)$, meaning the $Y_t$ has the same distribution of $X$, weaker than the original statement ($Y_t=X_{T-t}$).
So I conjugate that: if $B'$ is just a standard BM, the resulting solution only has the same marginal distribution; To ensure the solutions are the same R.V.s, we may need some conditions on $B'_t$. So what conditions should we have?

These are good questions! This is not an answer (and I'd also like to see one!), but for 1. and 2. references in this answer may be useful. There's also this blog post, which refers to the papers of Song et al. (2021) and Anderson (1982).
